# Properly handling sort crashing due to out of disk space

Tags: sort

I run `sort` on large files (think 500GB+) on a HPC system.  Multiple `sorts` may be running on a single node, and when the 370GB RAM limit imposed on `sort` jobs is exceeded, `sort` goes to a 1TB `/scratch` disk on the node.  When `/scratch` runs out of space, sort crashes as expected.  I would like to clean up the specific files that were created by that instance of `sort` to make room for the other instances of `sort`.  Is there any way to determine which files `sort` created?

Comment: What `sort` are you using? Is it the GNU coreutils variant, or are you on a BSD system or some other Unix?

Comment: coreutils. Thanks

Comment: This is the current command I'm using: ```sort --parallel 4 -T /scratch -k1,1 -k2,2 -k5,5nr -t$'\t' unsorted.tab > sorted.tab``` on a 500GB file.

Answer (score 3):

To clean up after a failed `sort` run, you need to know exactly what temporary files were left in place after the utility terminates.  This is made easier if you restrict the creation of temporary files to a directory that you later remove.

You may create a temporary directory using `mktemp`, and then make `sort` use that directory by setting `TMPDIR` to its pathname.

```bsh
tmpdir=$( mktemp -d /scratch/sort-XXXXXXXX )
trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'" EXIT

TMPDIR=$tmpdir sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2 -k5,5nr -o sorted.tab --parallel=4 unsorted.tab
```

This creates a temporary directory under `/scratch`, assigns its pathname to the shell variable `tmpdir` and then sets the environment variable `TMPDIR` to this value in the invocation of `sort`.

The `sort` utility may have a `-T` option that you could use as `-T "$tmpdir"`, but setting `TMPDIR` in the environment of `sort` is portable.

The trap that I set after calling `mktemp` makes sure that the directory is deleted whenever the script exits. You could obviously just do `rm -rf "$tmpdir"` after calling `sort` instead of using the trap.